# Lazy load library into another library Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a library(DashboardModule) in Angular 6 and it has below routes(I know library doesn't need route but it's necessary in this example) :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        children: [
             {
                 path: 'user',            
                 loadChildren: '../substitute/substitute.module#SubstituteModule' // 1
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

1- `SubstituteModule` is another library, is it possible to lazy load a library into another library for using in other project?how?(`SubstituteModule` into `DashboardModule`)

Note: if I add the `SubstituteModule` lib inside `DashboardModule` lib without lazy load, the bundle's size of project will be too much, because of this, I need lazy load here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show:
1. The error thrown in the dev-tools console when you go to `/user`
or
2. The folder structure of your app ?

Comment: 1-Error when go to `/user`: `Cannot find 'SubstituteModule' in './substitute/substitute.module'` 
2- both library are installed in node_modules and I use `DashboardModule` in app.module.(actually import `AdminLayout` from `DashboardModule`)
   Note: `SubstituteModule` is inside `DashboardModule`